# What is my Tax Liability Germany when working in multiple countries?

Tags: taxes, germany, liability, greece

I am currently working for a Company in Germany for 1 month and after that I will be working for another 5 months in Greece (from distance for the same company) where my permanent residence is. I was informed I will experience limited tax liability.

Can someone explain me the context of this and more specifically how much tax I am going to pay and in which country?

Comment: You were informed by who exactly? And did they say anything else than just "experience limited tax liability"? Where exactly will you be when you work "in Greece from distance"? Basically, where exactly will you be sitting in an office chair, because that's what matters.

Comment: I have edited the post to be more specific. The payroll team informed me about this and that is all they 've said. I will be staying in Greece and I will work for them from distance

Comment: So you will be working for a German company with a German labor contract but part of the work time will be done remotely and you will be in Greece? I would expect you pay income taxes on the full 6 months in Germany. The interesting question is whether Greece wants some taxes from you as well.

Comment: Quarage, you pay taxes where you work. Sitting in an office chair in Greece means you work in Greece and pay tax there.